# Does Hu moments remain unchanged for a slightly changed detected shape-OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, object-detection

Below you can see a set of binary shapes that belong to the same object being detected in a video based on color as main feature representation.
[image: shapes of object of interest]

Since i'm depending on object color in the detection, there might be other irrelevant object presented in the binary mask image because they simply have similar color distribution as the target object of interest (the object to be detected is red car or green car for example)

I tried to distinguish the object based the area and aspect ratio. However, it didn't work efficiently as there were other detected irrelevant objects which their area and aspect ratio fall with in the boundaries of the object to be detected as shown in the below image.

[image: object and non object]

In the image above the target object is the top white spot.

And because it is hard to maintain color consistency due ti illumination effects, i'm trying to distinguish the object of interest using additional features such as Hu Moments, since Hu Moment are Scale, position and rotation invariant for a given shape

As you can see, the set of masks (see first image) captured from different frames of the video slightly differ from each other.

**So would the Hu Moments despite this slight change in shape differ?, and if they remain the same how can i use them as additional property to make the detection more accurate?**

I've calculated the 7 Hu-Moments for different frames and the result was:

```
HuMoments
[[ 2.08520054e-01]
[ 1.69631372e-02]
[ 7.21551810e-05]
[ 6.90080950e-06]
[ 1.42410779e-12]
[-1.68289072e-07]
[-1.53980330e-10]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.06895709e-01]
[ 1.60840647e-02]
[ 3.30558368e-06]
[ 1.11390263e-07]
[-6.73641826e-14]
[ 1.41245011e-08]
[-5.54413536e-15]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.13862698e-01]
[ 1.92304207e-02]
[ 1.59852416e-06]
[ 3.25416763e-07]
[ 2.14353017e-13]
[ 1.50649139e-08]
[-9.55954816e-14]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.14002398e-01]
[ 1.92008910e-02]
[ 4.97181458e-06]
[ 4.78948215e-07]
[ 3.76015109e-13]
[-3.15822288e-08]
[-6.36277450e-13]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.06781829e-01]
[ 1.61130389e-02]
[ 8.62252599e-06]
[ 2.40464402e-07]
[ 2.97886471e-13]
[ 3.07837011e-09]
[-1.76507042e-13]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.05995932e-01]
[ 1.60756861e-02]
[ 7.67493642e-07]
[ 9.51817986e-08]
[ 2.14701063e-14]
[-3.25280940e-09]
[-1.41721342e-14]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.05805316e-01]
[ 1.54879330e-02]
[ 1.22114797e-04]
[ 1.25265644e-05]
[ 8.26008946e-11]
[-2.83389042e-07]
[-4.82914455e-10]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.09471113e-01]
[ 1.72160248e-02]
[ 2.20128873e-05]
[ 1.49897869e-06]
[-2.30866693e-12]
[-1.57913774e-07]
[-8.29529391e-12]]
HuMoments
[[2.15147844e-01]
[1.93443753e-02]
[8.08244156e-06]
[3.97563367e-06]
[2.20658357e-11]
[5.52855740e-07]
[4.58034173e-12]]
HuMoments
[[2.15429849e-01]
[1.93910849e-02]
[3.17392350e-05]
[1.45996626e-05]
[3.13970937e-10]
[1.99024297e-06]
[1.38642988e-11]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.11382574e-01]
[ 1.77909581e-02]
[ 2.79886054e-06]
[ 4.41359415e-06]
[ 1.53146745e-11]
[ 5.02198776e-07]
[-2.46891717e-12]]
HuMoments
[[2.12028845e-01]
[1.81061901e-02]
[1.15214622e-05]
[4.73220650e-06]
[3.35997756e-11]
[6.36751845e-07]
[9.59204224e-12]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.10406753e-01]
[ 1.72785541e-02]
[ 5.29421210e-06]
[ 9.58072012e-08]
[-2.65557753e-14]
[-1.25685175e-08]
[ 6.28538516e-14]]
HuMoments
[[2.17360183e-01]
[2.02630904e-02]
[6.14574197e-05]
[9.08990258e-06]
[2.13670968e-10]
[1.27309750e-06]
[2.24332748e-11]]
HuMoments
[[ 2.14532303e-01]
[ 1.87193203e-02]
[ 4.37330273e-05]
[ 5.07043463e-06]
[ 5.19617629e-11]
[-8.75846866e-08]
[-5.47804462e-11]]
```

Thanks in advance

For tests below are images of the object masks at different timestamp  with and without irrelevant objects and one of the original images

[image: original_1]

[image: original_2]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Please don’t change your question after someone posted an answer. You completely invalidated my answer, making me look like I’m telling you things you already know and not answering your question. Instead, accept the answer you got and write a new question. If you click on the “edited” link you can get the new question back, copy-paste it into a new post.

Comment: If you post a new question, do make sure to include the code you used to compute rectangularity, it might be wrong.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry for the inconvience i made. You're absolutely write. I didn't consider that. I'll post a new question and leave a tag

Comment: @CrisLuengo. I've made a new post. would appreciate to get some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many shape features you could experiment with.

Hu moments are certainly worth trying out for your case. As with most features, they change by a small amount when the shape changes by a small amount, and change more strongly when the shape changes more strongly. However, this statement only holds for the continuous domain. In the discrete domain, we have a set of pixels that approximate the object being imaged, and the shape of this set changes with (subpixel) translation, with rotation and with scaling. The smaller the objects, the larger the relative differences introduced by these changes.

Hu moments are computed based on the central moments of up to 3rd order. The higher the order, the more the moments will vary with small changes. Higher order moments are more sensitive to noise.

The first two Hu moments only use second order central moments, and are therefore less noise sensitive than the other ones, and more suitable for very small objects. Second order moments describe the best-fit ellipse to the shape. The first two Hu moments therefore describe the shape as an ellipse: elongation and similarity to the ellipse.

Other features you should add to this set are area, and maybe things like convexity or solidity, and [Podczeck shapes](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/features.html#shape_features_PodczeckShapes) (especially the similarity to a square seems relevant).

You will have to set some thresholds around your ideal values, and you should determine these thresholds from a collection of example shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question by showing the 7-Hu Moments of the target object for different frames.However, only the first two hu values change slightly as you can see. So do you think  choosing the object based on these two values would work ?. @Cris Luengo

Comment: @k.jbaili: Indeed, didn’t think of that. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: @ I will give it a try. However, it is hard to threshold the target object based on area, ratio ,etc, because other irrrelevant objects do fall in the defined thresholds boundaries and thus being chosen. For example, see the first image (two convex shape, one is the target object(top) and the other irrelevant (bottom).@Cris Luengo

Comment: @k.jbaili: That is the purpose of adding multiple features: the more features you use, the more you constrain the objects accepted. The shape needs to fit within each of your thresholds, not only one. Size alone is not sufficient, but size together with some shape features is. Note that shape alone cannot distinguish a rectangle of the right size from a much larger rectangle. The two shapes in the first image will have a different rectangularity measure according to Podczeck.

Comment: `@k.jbaili`  The first Podczeck shape (number 0) a/(w\*h), which is a measure of rectangularity, is what I suggested to you before in your other post. a is the area of the contour and w*h is the area of its bounding box. So try filtering on both area of contour and rectangularity as defined by a/(w\*h)

Comment: @fmw42. thank you mr. Weinhaus for your great support. If i may ask, what is the difference between rectengularity and solidity?

Comment: @k.jbaili: Solidity is typically defined as the ratio of the area to the area of the convex hull. The convex hull can be (typically is) smaller than the bounding box. It thus measures how close to a convex shape it is. Rectangularity measures how close to a rectangle it is.

Comment: Solidity uses the area of the convex hull in the denominator. Rectangularity use the bounding box area in the denominator. Rectangularity means how close to a full rectangle it is. Solidity means how close to a full convex hull it is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull and https://www.learnopencv.com/convex-hull-using-opencv-in-python-and-c/

Comment: Consider building a vector of features from your ideal data and building another vector from your input data. Measure the similarity between both vectors to determine if the input is similar to what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @fmw42,. I've updated the question . would appreciate your opinion

Comment: @eldesgraciado.  I've updated the question . would appreciate your opinion

Comment: @Cris Luengo, i've updated the question, would appreciate having your opinion

Comment: @eldesgraciado. I'm not sure if i know how to do this programmically (i mean by building the vector and do the similarity check). is your idea not the same as i did above with the if statements ?